# Array to string

Tags: arrays, string, codeigniter

I have an `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" } }`

How could break it down to a string as I am only getting one value?

**Model:**

```
$table = $this->_table_products_manufacturers;
        $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT $table.id FROM $table WHERE $table.id = $manufacturer_id");

        return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$table = $this->_table_products_manufacturers;
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT $table.id FROM $table WHERE $table.id = $manufacturer_id");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result[0]['id'];
```

Will it help?

Comment: THANK YOU didnt think of it like that

Comment: If this replies your query, please accept this as "answer". Thank you :)